# Custom template for shipping method item

Tags: magento2

I need to create a custom template for shipping method item

> view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html

However, this template file has allready been overwritten by another module, so this method is not working.

```
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="shippingMethodItemTemplate" xsi:type="string">DM_Checkout/shipping-method-item</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

The other module looks like this:

> vendor/quickpay/magento2/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="shippingMethodItemTemplate" xsi:type="string">QuickPay_Gateway/shipping/shipping-method-item</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

What would be the best approach to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add the template to your theme under the other module's name, like:

```
app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/QuickPay_Gateway/...
```

What you are doing like this is actually overriding the other module's template without having to edit a file in the vendor/ directory